# How to Android in-app remote memory profiling and reporting using Firebase Crashlitycs?

Tags: android, out-of-memory, crashlytics

I'm inspecting my app with Android Profiler and everithyng is going well, but when users use my app, ramdomly the memory is fullfilling and the app crashes. I want to knwo if is it possible to remote inspect the memory to add some report into crashlytics reports.

Appearly the Native Memory is the problem

Thanks!